create and execute a plan to determine the reliability of read replay for meter 49
Description
We need to create and execute a plan to determine the reliability of read replay for meter 49.  If it turns out we can’t reliably replay the reads, we need to stop using it for automation purposes until we figure out why the reads are not being reliably replayed
Generated Benchmark files and compares the result in SQL and Oracle
